# How to find directories and iteratively use in a docker_compose task in Ansible?

Tags: docker-compose, ansible

I have multiple Linux boxes running multiple docker-compose. The docker-compose.yaml files are in subdirectories inside ~/docker of all machines and I'm writing a playbook in my notebook so I can bring down all dockers remotely in one shot.

How could I run `docker_compose` task in a loop for the results of `find`? After reading some documentation about the [find module](http://%20https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html), [docker_compose module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_compose_module.html) and [variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html), I still don't understand how to put the pieces together. This is my first experience with Ansible, and here's where I'm stuck at:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:

    - name: Find all docker-compose directories
      find:
        paths: ~/docker
        recurse: no
        file_type: directory

    - name: Run docker-compose down on every directory inside ~/docker
      docker_compose:
        project_src: docker/postgres # un-hardcode directory and use the results from the task above iteratively
        state: absent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is [`register:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) and then [`with_items:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/lookup/items.html)

```yaml
    - name: Find all docker-compose directories
      find:
        # be careful about using `~` as that's usually only meaningful to the shell
        paths: ~/docker
        recurse: no
        file_type: directory
      register: docker_dirs

    - name: Run docker-compose down on every directory inside ~/docker
      docker_compose:
        project_src: '{{ item }}'
        state: absent
      with_items: '{{ docker_dirs.files | map(attribute="path") | list }}'
```